# How to get records with maximum Sr in SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a table `DiagDetail` with following structure:

[image]

I want to get distinct records with maximum `Sr`. I tried to use `Group by` but it's not working because every column should have different values.

I want the following result:

[image]

**Note:** I am using MS Access.

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select dd.*
from diagdetail as dd
where dd.sr = (select max(dd2.sr)
               from diagdetail as dd2
               where dd2.? = dd.?
              );
```

The `?` is for the column or columns that you would use for `group by`.

Comment: It Worked. Thank you.